# Is it possible in AzureDevOps Pipeline to copy previously built artifact to another build pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm building an azure DevOps pipeline in which one of the steps is to refer an already prebuilt package and copy it to the current pipeline. I'm following below step which is working fine, but I think there should be a possibility in azure DevOps to directly copy from the artifcatory to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`
Current Approach:
In Azure repo: (I have mentioned the prebuilt artifact/package) inside
`requirements_generic_bash.txt`

now in my pipeline.yml

```
- bash: |
      echo PythonV3
      python3 -m venv venv
      source venv/bin/activate
      python --version
      http_proxy="xxxx"
      https_proxy="xxx"
      index_url="https://actory.com/artifactory/api/simple"
      extra_index_url="https://actorycom/artifactory/api/simple"
      python -m pip install -r $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/requirements/requirements_generic_bash.txt --index-url ${index_url} --extra-index-url ${extra_index_url}         
      deactivate
    displayName: Install GenericBash from Artifactory

  - bash: |
      cp -r venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/* $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    displayName: Copy files to ArtifactStagingDirectory
```

so my question is is there any way '**Copy files to ArtifactStagingDirectory**' can be done directly instead of virtual env ? if so then how?

Answer (score -1):

There is a task in pipeline that might meet your need.

Copy files task can copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths.
So you can set the already prebuilt package path in Source Folder and set the Target folder like below.
[image]

If you would like to use Yaml file, then you can set it as below.
[image]

More detail information about this task, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: This won't work in numerous situations: If the next build runs on a different agent. If you're using the hosted agent.